# Bind single tableview for 2 data sources and update based on selected segment with Bond

Tags: swift, xcode, reactive-programming, rx-swift, swiftbond

I am trying to bind single `UITableView` with 2 data sources.
My code is like this

```
viewModel?.dataSource?.currentYear?.bind(to: tableViewMonths, cellType: StatementExportMonthTableViewCell.self) { (cell, name) in
            cell.updateWith(month: name)
        }

viewModel?.dataSource?.previousYear?.bind(to: tableViewMonths, cellType: StatementExportMonthTableViewCell.self) { (cell, name) in
            cell.updateWith(month: name)
        }
```

I cant figure out how to show correct data into table view based on selected segment index.
I know i can define one main data source and based on segment selection I should assign respective data source to that instance and reload tableview from that.

But I am trying to simplify it if Bond already has that functionality in-built.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it would be simpler to do if you merged the two data sources into one and used it that way.

Comment: Thats what I am doing currently but I am curious if it can be achieved without using a separate data source and reloading the table accordingly.

Comment: Even if you could, doing so is against the reactive paradigm. Your reactive code should be output centric.